# Where is the source code of os.pipe in CPython

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python built-in lib *subprocess* and read its source code.
When I want to read the implementation of *os.pipe*, I couldn't find the definition of it.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py
Could anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation for low-level OS-dependent primitives isn't at the Python layer; it's hidden away in the `posix` (UNIX-like) or `nt` (Windows) module, a C extension, and just imported and published via the Python level `os` module.

Conveniently, both `posix` and `nt` are implemented in the same file, [`posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c) (it just gets a different name when compiled depending on platform), so you can find all the info there (you just have to make sure you're reading the part for your target platform).

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your direction.